# FirebaseInstaceId, InstanceIdResult deprecated

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-cloud-messaging

How do I change this code since FirebaseInstanceId and InstanceIdResult are deprecated? It also states 'cannot resolve method getToken()' from the code.

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getId().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {
            String token = instanceIdResult.getToken();
            if (!token.equals(session.getData(Session.KEY_FCM_ID))) {
                UpdateToken(token, MainActivity.this);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how you should get the token. All those methods are deprecated. Nowadays, the solution is:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            String token = task.getResult();
            //Do what you need to do with your token
            Log.d(TAG, token);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: How can I receive Id as well? I had     FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().instanceId.addOnSuccessListener from which I can receive both id and token. How can I write a code to reveive them both as it seems that I need two on success listeners for id/ token now.

Comment: @GigaCoder [FirebaseInstanceId](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId.html) class is deprecated. The new class that should be used is [FirebaseMessaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessaging). So there is no need to get an ID.

Comment: But I was sending the ID to SharedPreferenced. You are sure that there is no need to do that?

Comment: @GigaCoder You can check both documentations linked in the previous comment yourself.